# Should an Activity unbind from a started Foreground Service in onPause()?

Tags: android

If an activity wants to bind to a started foreground service, should it bind in onCreate() and unbind in onDestroy() or bind in onResume() and unbind in onPause()?

The content of the activity is dependent on data stored within the service, so it must be connected to display correctly. Is there any advantage to the latter option?

Comment: Take a look at the following link to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting up the `ServiceConnection` takes some time, binding to the `Service` in `onResume()` may be way too late for your app to work smoothly. In addition to that, `onPause()` will also be called e.g. when you show an `AlertDialog`, so unbinding there means you'd have to "re-bind" as soon as the dialog is dismissed and - again - wait for the `ServiceConnection` to be up and running.

The documentation on [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Additional_Notes)  states

> You usually pair the binding and unbinding during matching bring-up
> and tear-down moments of the client's lifecycle, as described in the
> following examples:
>
> - If you need to interact with the service only while your activity is visible, you should bind during onStart() and unbind during
>   onStop().
> - If you want your activity to receive responses even while it is stopped in the background, then you can bind during onCreate() and
>   unbind during onDestroy(). Beware that this implies that your activity
>   needs to use the service the entire time it's running (even in the
>   background), so if the service is in another process, then you
>   increase the weight of the process and it becomes more likely that the
>   system will kill it.

So in your case you can use `onStart()`/ `onStop()`